# Loops for enumerated types

Tags: enum, code-complete

I'm currently reading *Code Complete* by Steve McConnell. In section 12.6, Enumerated Types, he says that we can define first and last entries like limits:

> ***Define the first and last entries of an enumeration for use as loop limits*** Defining the first and last elements in an enumeration to be
> *Color_First*, *Color_Last*, *Country_First*, *Country_Last*, and so on allows you to write a loop that loops through the elements of an
> enumeration. You set up the enumerated type by using explicit values,
> as shown here:
>
> **Visual Basic Example of Setting First and Last Values in an Enumerated Type**
>
> ```vb
> Public Enum Country
>  Country_First = 0
>  Country_China = 0
>  Country_England = 1
>  Country_France = 2
>  Country_Germany = 3
>  Country_India = 4
>  Country_Japan = 5
>  Country_Usa = 6
>  Country_Last = 6
> End Enum
> ```
>
> Now the *Country_First* and *Country_Last* values can be used as loop
> limits:
>
> **Good Visual Basic Example of Looping Through Elements in an Enumeration**
>
> ```vb
> ' compute currency conversions from US currency to target currency
> Dim usaCurrencyConversionRate( Country_Last ) As Single
> Dim iCountry As Country
> For iCountry = Country_First To Country_Last
>  usaCurrencyConversionRate( iCountry ) = ConversionRate( Country_Usa, iCountry )
> Next
> ```

Why do we need duplicated indices on the edges for enumerated type?

Comment: I'd imagine a nearby paragraph explains just that, but probably because iterating from first to last is more intent revealing than iterating from China to the USA.

Comment: Indeed finding a PDF it explicitly tells you that this _"... allows you to write a loop that loops through the elements of an enumeration... [these] values can be used as loop limits"_ with the VB example `For iCountry = Country_First To Country_Last`.

Comment: Ok, nice. Why indices should be duplicated?

Comment: Again, for one thing, _"because iterating from first to last is more intent revealing than iterating from China to the USA"_.

Comment: @EugZ: There are duplicate values because there are duplicate meanings. Referring to `USA` and referring to "the last value" are two different concepts that may currently overlap (due to `USA` being the last value) but could one day diverge (when another country is added).

Comment: @EugZ _"Why indices"_ Tangentially: that integer value is not an index. They do not have to be continuous, nor do they have to be 0- or 1-indexed. You _can_ set these values to mimic those of an index, but that's just your choice to do so then.

Comment: @Flater the risks of discontinuous enumerations (e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8 for bit flags) are also covered in that section!

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Haven't read it so I can't comment on the reasoning, but I personally dislike the notion that you should rely on continuity here. The integer values of the enum should not be of concern to the enum's consumer, and could be completely arbitrary for all the consumer cares. The posted answer is the correct one, but I seriously dislike the allround approach there. Unless VB does not have another way to enumerate its enum values - at which point I'd still call it a dirty workaround but at least one in absence of a good way of doing things.

Comment: "Why do we need duplicated indices on the edges for enumerated type?" - Because iterating like this on enums is very weird and not really idiomatic, and you have to create this hack-ish aberration to make it work. There are better ways of doing this with minimal extra scaffolding that don't result in such a terrible headache for your future you five weeks down the line.

Comment: Honestly, this particular example is terrible advice. "Country_Last" is a valid value for this enum but it what it means can change down the line just because you added another value to the list. This breaks the entire reason of using enums in the first place.

Comment: For C# at least, [use this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0) instead of the solution proposed in the book. It's far easier on the mind and prevents strange mistakes - all without corrupting your enum types.

Comment: ...Seriously, for some reason it is extremely upsetting to me that this... _hack_ was published in a book as something serious that you should do. Argh, this is horrible!

Comment: @Flater at least for Vb.Net, [there is this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/how-to-iterate-through-an-enumeration). Way less hackish than the proposed solution on the OP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's say for some reason you want to iterate over all countries. "That's easy", you say:

```
for (i = Country_China; i <= Country_Usa; i++) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

and you write that loop construct at lots of places in your code.

The next day, your product owner comes along and says "Hey EugZ, we're launching in Albania soon, can you make sure the product supports that?". "Sure", you say, and think about adding `Country_Albania` to your enum. Where do you add `Country_Albania`?

1. Before `Country_China`, in order to maintain the alphabetical ordering? You now need to go and rewrite every instance of your loop construct to start at `Country_Albania` rather than `Country_China` - and you may well miss one.
2. After `Country_Usa`, in order to maintain the existing values of the enum? Same problem.
3. You *could* put `Country_Albania` in the middle of the list of countries. While this wouldn't break the loop construct, you've *implicitly* and undocumentedly made `Country_China` and `Country_Usa` magic values in the enum which must always be first and last, and all sorts of things will break if anyone ever changes them. Not good.

Adding explicit values for `Country_First` and `Country_Last` avoids a lot of these and similar issues; given the small amount of work needed to do it, it's almost a no-brainer.

Comment: I'm not sure what language this is in, it seems strange not to have some way to get all possible values from an enum type.

Comment: @bdsl Certainly neither C nor C# (`[Flags]`) let you do that.

Comment: @PhilipKendall [C# absolutely lets you do that](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getnames?view=net-6.0), for both name [and values](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.getvalues?view=net-6.0)

Comment: "Adding explicit values for Country_First and Country_Last avoids a lot of these and similar issue" - It _adds_ one extra point of failure, however - if you slap Country_Albania _after_ Country_Last, your code won't work as it should. Adding something to the list of countries will never be just adding it to it and calling it a day - you _have_ to remember to change Country_Last, too. Which is not a usual thing...

Comment: @T.Sar That does not give you all the legal values of a `[Flags]` enum.

Comment: @PhilipKendall And neither the suggested method on Code Complete. But the options I linked are enough for the issue at hand. [Flags] are a different beast altogether.